# Excel VBA Save Dialogue runtime error 1001

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am quite new to excel and tried to create the save button for the invoice but i ran into some road block, the code itself run ok until I click on save button it sometime show error 400 and sometime show runtime error 1001, may I have some advice please

```
Sub NextInvoice()
    Range("F4").Value = Range("F4").Value + 1
    Range("A17:E32").ClearContents    
End Sub

Sub SaveInvWithNewName()
    ThisWorkbook.Save 'Save Current workbook in current name

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .InitialFileName = Range("F1").Text & Range("F4").Text  'Specify folder - can also include default filename in here too
        If .Show Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMarcoEnabled

        End If
    Cancel = True
    End With
End Sub
```

`

Comment: Is `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMarcoEnabled` just a typo when you entered the question or is it in your code? It has to be `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`. Always use `option explicit` to catch those typos.

Comment: as silly as it seems, it is the typo problem nice catch Thomas :(

Comment: In the VBA-Editor: Tools- > Options -> Editor -> Require Variable Declaration